# How to log all properties from an object in google script

Tags: arrays, google-maps, oop

I am trying to get all the properties of array object routes to be logged 1 by 1, however, it's giving undefined error.

```
function testRoutes () { //Calling the maps API and new direction finder.
   var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()  
   .setOrigin('Kharadar, Karachi')
   .setDestination('Guru Mandir, Karachi')
   .setMode(Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.DRIVING) //By default driving.
   .getDirections();
   //We have got all the directions now from origin to destination in test variable.
//   var route = directions.routes[0].legs[0].steps[1];
//   var route2 = directions.routes[0];
var route = directions.routes;
for (var propt in route) {
    Logger.log(route[0].propt);
  }
//Logger.log(route[0].summary);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you loop through properties of variable route it should be

```
for (var propt in route) {
    Logger.log(route[propt]);
}
```